# ggplot2: scatterplot with two variables (measured on the same scale) on the y-axis: how do I change the aesthetics & add seperate regression lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, aes, geom

For my thesis, I am making scatterplots in APA format in R.
So far, my code is as follows, and it works great for plotting just one variable with confidence interval and regression line:

```
  scatterplot=ggplot(dat, aes(x=STAIT, y=valence))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method=lm,se=T, fullrange=T,colour='black')+
    labs(x='STAI-T score', y='Report length')+
    apatheme
```

However, I have two variables that were initially measured on the same 0-100 scale: valence and arousal. Instead of two seperate plots, I thought it would be nice to add both variables in a single plot, using 'valence/arousal score' as the ylab and open/closed dots to define which data points come from which variable, a bit like in [this example I found online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqxUP.png).
In that example, however, the data comes from different groups. So that code doesn't work on my data.
I've tried different things, and the closest I get, is with the following code:

```
sp.both=ggplot(dat, aes(x=STAIT))+
  geom_point(aes(y=valence)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=arousal)) +
  apatheme
```

This gives me a scatterplot with data points of both of the variables added in the same plot.
However, I need the data points of one score to be visually different from the other, and I want to add two seperate regression lines for each variable. But everything I've tried so far, has resulted in errors, and I cannot find any examples online of people trying to do the same thing.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some random example data you could achieve your desired like so:

It's best to reshape your data to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` which gives us two new cols, one with the names of the variables and one with the corresponding values. After reshaping you could map the values on y and set different shapes and linetypes by mapping the variables column on `shape` and `linetype`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  STAIT = runif(20, 0, 1),
  valence = runif(20, 0, 1),
  arousal = runif(20, 0, 1)
)

dat_long <- dat %>%
  pivot_longer(c(valence, arousal), names_to = "var", values_to = "value")

ggplot(dat_long, aes(x = STAIT, y = value, linetype = var, shape = var)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", size = .5)
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it, with the following code:

```
sp.both = ggplot(dat,aes(x=STAIT)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, aes(y=arousal)) +
  geom_point(shape = 1, aes(y=valence)) +
  labs(x='STAI-T score', y= 'valence/arousal score')+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=T,fullrange=T,colour='black',aes(y=arousal))+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=T,fullrange=T,linetype ='dashed',colour='black',aes(y=valence))+
  apatheme
```

The only thing I haven't figured out yet, is how to now add a legend with both the linetype (solid/dashed) and the corresponding datapoint (solid/open) and the variable it belongs to.
But Stefan's example solved this problem, and I prefer the way the plot then looks visually as well. So that's definitely a better solution to this problem. Thanks!